# Django blog page, admin page stopped working

Tags: django, django-admin

I try to code a blog with Django and it worked pretty well until I couldn't open the admin page anymore: `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`.
I created a superuser I could login to the admin page but then I changed something else but I can't say what. The blog with the database and my personal was working except the admin page. Do you have any idea why that happened? Appreciate any help.

The following image shows the failure message:
[image]

Here is my code:

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'taggit',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'thomkell.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'thomkell.wsgi.application'

# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

#this code
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

# Default primary key field type

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media/"

#ckeditor upload path
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH="uploads/"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = { ...
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    path('ckeditor/',include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've installed the Django sites framework with `django.contrib.sites` in your installed apps but you probably haven't set everything else up that is needed. If you put `SITE_ID=1` in your settings.py, I expect your page will load - at the moment it isn't receiving anything at all - but you should read through the rest of the framework docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/sites/